# Strip the date and keep the time

Tags: r, datetime

Lots of people ask how to strip the time and keep the date, but what about the other way around?  Given:

```
myDateTime <- "11/02/2014 14:22:45"
```

I would like to see:

```
myTime
[1] "14:22:45"
```

Time zone not necessary.

I've already tried (from other answers)

```
as.POSIXct(substr(myDateTime, 12,19),format="%H:%M:%S")
```

[1] "2013-04-13 14:22:45 NZST"

The purpose is to analyse events recorded over several days by time of day only.

Thanks

**Edit:**

It turns out there's no pure "time" object, so every time must also have a date.

In the end I used

```
as.POSIXct(as.numeric(as.POSIXct(myDateTime)) %% 86400, origin = "2000-01-01")
```

rather than the character solution, because I need to do arithmetic on the results.  This solution is similar to my original one, except that the date can be controlled consistently - "2000-01-01" in this case, whereas my attempt just used the current date at runtime.

Comment: I eventually stumbled upon chron, which has an object of class "times".  This makes addition much easier, e.g. 18:00 + 12:00 = 1.25 days.

Comment: you can also use the `hms` package after calling `format()`, i.e. `hms::as.hms(x)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the time within a GMT day is useful for your problem, you can get this with `%%`, the remainder operator, taking the remainder modulo `86400` (the number of seconds in a day).

```
stamps <- c("2013-04-12 19:00:00", "2010-04-01 19:00:01", "2018-06-18 19:00:02")
as.numeric(as.POSIXct(stamps)) %% 86400
## [1] 0 1 2
```

Answer (score 28):

I think you're looking for the `format` function.

```
(x <- strptime(myDateTime, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
#[1] "2014-02-11 14:22:45"
format(x, "%H:%M:%S")
#[1] "14:22:45"
```

That's `character`, not "time", but would work with something like `aggregate` if that's what you mean by "analyse events recorded over several days by time of day only."

Comment: I am facing an issue in strptime function. If I add a text just before the date like this:
strptime("hello Tue, 23 Mar 2010 14:36:38 -0400",  "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")
#NA
Any idea where is the issue

Comment: @Ankit you have to account for it in the `format` argument.  Try this: `strptime("hello Tue, 23 Mar 2010 14:36:38 -0400", "hello %a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S %z")`

Comment: @GSee Great answer. This is what I was looking for.