# How to create one date/time column in a dataframe in R?

Tags: r, date, datetime, time

The data frame I am working with:

```
head(ossub3)

date---------|os5 | os6 |  os7| os8 | _ _Year| Month|Day|Hour|Minutes 
11/15/2015|10.06|16.94|10.63|12.94  |2015|11|15| 12|08
```

I have all of the time units separated into columns. I would like one datetime column in R. I have tried the solutions on [R tick data : merging date and time into a single object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11609252/r-tick-data-merging-date-and-time-into-a-single-object) and on [Strip the date and keep the time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15982722/strip-the-date-and-keep-the-time) because when I try to

```
#Combine Date 

ossub3$Date<-as.POSIXlt(paste(ossub3$Year, ossub3$Month, ossub3$Day, sep="-"), 
    tz = "US/Central", format = "%Y-%m-%d")

#Create new column called Time which concatenates Hour, Minute as a POSIXlt 

ossub3$sec=rep(00,nrow(ossub3))
ossub3$Time<-as.POSIXlt(paste(ossub3$Hour, ossub3$Minute,ossub3$sec, sep=":"), 
    tz = "US/Central", format = "%H:%M")
```

I get today's date in my time so I can't combine it with the date.  What is going on here?

Answer (score 1):

One last step is needed:

```
ossub3$sec=rep(00,nrow(ossub3))
ossub3$Time<-as.POSIXlt(paste(ossub3$Hour, ossub3$Minute,ossub3$sec, sep=":"), tz = "US/Central", format = "%H:%M")

# Excluding the date information and preserving just the time
ossub3$JustTime <- sapply(ossub3$Time, function(x) {format(x, format = "%T")})
```

By doing so, you are removing the date information (which is the current date and meaningless in your case), and you can attach *just the time* to the date you have in the other column (`ossub3$Date`).

Comment: Hey Matin-I could be completely incompetent but I enter in the code as written and I got an Error.  Specifically, Error during wrapup: invalid 'trim' argument.  Do I need to make "x" anything or is there something I am missing?

Comment: It should have been explicitly mentioned `format = "%T"`. Check the answer now.

Comment: I wonder if you checked the updated answer. If this is the solution, please mark my response as the answer to your question.

Comment: Sorry my wife had a baby and I haven't looked at it in awhile